# Glassfish ssl console handshake exception

Tags: 14.04, ssl, glassfish

I'm running ubuntu 14.04 server.

I installed glassfish 4.1.

I want to acces the console from outside so I did

```
asadmin --host localhost --port 4848 enable-secure-admin
```

After that step calling `www.myhost.com:4848/console/` is giving me a security exception in the browser because of self-signed certificate.  Ok, it's normal.  I can accept the exception and everything is ok.

Now I have a startssl certificated for www.myhost.com.

So I did

```
keytool -delete -alias s1as -keystore keystore.jks
keytool -importcert -keystore keystore.jks -storepass changeit -file www.myhost.com.crt -alias s1as
keytool -importcert -keystore keystore.jks -storepass changeit -file ca.crt -alias startcom.ca -trustcacerts
keytool -importcert -keystore keystore.jks -storepass changeit -file sub.class1.server.ca.crt -alias startcom.ca.sub -trustcacerts
```

But now `asadmin start-domain` gives me in the log

```
[2015-02-20T09:55:58.021+0100] [glassfish 4.1] [SEVERE] [] [] [tid: _ThreadID=57 _ThreadName=Thread-9] [timeMillis: 1424422558021] [levelValue: 1000] [[
  java.io.IOException: Cannot bind to URL [rmi://www.myhost.com.be:8686/jmxrmi]: javax.naming.CommunicationException [Root exception is java.rmi.ConnectIOException: error during JRMP connection establishment; nested exception is:
        javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure]
        at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectorServer.newIOException(RMIConnectorServer.java:826)
        at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectorServer.start(RMIConnectorServer.java:431)
        at org.glassfish.admin.mbeanserver.RMIConnectorStarter.start(RMIConnectorStarter.java:319)
        at org.glassfish.admin.mbeanserver.JMXStartupService$JMXConnectorsStarterThread.startConnector(JMXStartupService.java:313)
        at org.glassfish.admin.mbeanserver.JMXStartupService$JMXConnectorsStarterThread.run(JMXStartupService.java:350)
Caused by: javax.naming.CommunicationException [Root exception is java.rmi.ConnectIOException: error during JRMP connection establishment; nested exception is:
        javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure]
        at com.sun.jndi.rmi.registry.RegistryContext.rebind(RegistryContext.java:159)
        at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.url.GenericURLContext.rebind(GenericURLContext.java:249)
        at javax.naming.InitialContext.rebind(InitialContext.java:427)
        at javax.naming.InitialContext.rebind(InitialContext.java:427)
        at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectorServer.bind(RMIConnectorServer.java:641)
        at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectorServer.start(RMIConnectorServer.java:426)
        ... 3 more
Caused by: java.rmi.ConnectIOException: error during JRMP connection establishment; nested exception is:
        javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.createConnection(TCPChannel.java:304)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.newConnection(TCPChannel.java:202)
        at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.newCall(UnicastRef.java:341)
        at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub.rebind(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.jndi.rmi.registry.RegistryContext.rebind(RegistryContext.java:157)
        ... 8 more
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
        at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
        at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:154)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert(SSLSocketImpl.java:1979)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1086)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1332)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:709)
        at sun.security.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(AppOutputStream.java:122)
        at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
        at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:140)
        at java.io.DataOutputStream.flush(DataOutputStream.java:123)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.createConnection(TCPChannel.java:229)
        ... 12 more]]
```

And my server is accessible on port 8080 but not on ssl 8181 and 4848.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, after a lot of searches I found a solution working for me ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12860289/import-ssl-certificate-in-glassfish))

So, after a fresh install, go to `/opt/glassfish4/glassfish/domains/domain1/connfig` and download the startssl certs

```
wget https://www.startssl.com/certs/ca.pem
wget https://www.startssl.com/certs/sub.class1.server.ca.pem
```

Then concat those 2 certificates with my domain certificate

```
cat mydomain.crt ca.pem sub.class1.server.ca.pem > all.crt
```

And import in cacerts

```
keytool -import -trustcacerts -alias mycert -file all.crt -keystore cacerts.jks
```

Create a p12 file with my domain's private key

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -in all.crt -inkey mydomain.key -out mydomain.p12 -name mycert -CAfile ca.pem -caname immed
```

and import in keystore

```
keytool -importkeystore -deststorepass changeit -destkeypass changeit -destkeystore keystore.jks -srckeystore mydomain.p12 -srcstoretype PKCS12 -srcstorepass changeit -alias mycert
```

and finally change all `s1as` occurrences by `mycert` in `domain.xml`

```
sed -i 's|s1as|mycert|' domain.xml
```

Ok, now it's working even if I don't understand what I'm doing !

Answer (score 0):

my suggestion would be not to delete the initial s1as certificate and replace it with your own. keep in mind that there is another cacerts.jks keystone file which must be in sync...
for a clean glassfish installation check this here: https://www.nabisoft.com/tutorials/glassfish/installing-glassfish-41-on-ubuntu
My tutorial tells you also how to create your own (self signed) s1as and glassfish-instace certificate (it's too long to post it here).

After that import the certificate for your domain into keystore.jks (if you have received an intermediate certificate from your CA as well then you might need to import that first). no need to add you domains cert to cacerts.jks 
Make sure to change your http-listener2 (=https) to use your cert alias instead of s1as and restart Glassfish. that should work...

Comment: Thanks but I don't understand.  You delete the s1as alias in the keystore.jks than you recreate one and you create a myAlias.  So what's the difference with replacing s1as by another.  I tried leaving s1as, creating a mycert with my own certificate and replace all occurrences of s1as in domain.xml by mycert.  Same issue.